# How to use multiprocessing to download images using requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

My code snipped is fairly simple

```py
def download(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    with open(path, 'wb') as handle:
        handle.write(response.content)
```

But my code downloads almost 10,000 images which makes this process time intensive.

How can I make use of multiprocessing, and more importantly is it OK to use `multiprocessing` while using this snippet?

Comment: For code with high IO wait like downloads it is usually enough to use threads instead of processes.

Comment: I agree with @KlausD — in fact using multiprocessing instead of threads may actually make it slower.

Answer (score 2):

Basically this is an IO bound operation..so I would suggest you to use ***multithreading*** instead of ***multiprocessing***..

Try this..

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def download(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    with open(path, 'wb') as handle:
        handle.write(response.content)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    executor.map(download, urls) #urls=[list of url]
```

You can try changing the number of `max_workers` to speed up process as per your system's processing power.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you have a list `urls`, you can use multiprocessing like that:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def download(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    with open(path, 'wb') as handle:
        handle.write(response.content)

pool = Pool()
pool.map(download, urls)
```

Multiprocessing would increase the speed compared to one process. You can test it to see if the changes are significant in your case.